# Best way to remove an object from an array based on an attribute?

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to remove an object from an array based on an attribute?

`things = [{id:'23', color: 'blue'},{id:'54', color:'red'},{id:'132', color:'green'}]`

I know the `id` I need to remove is `'54'`. What is the best process remove that object from the array? Result should be `things = [{id:'23', color: 'blue'},{id:'132', color:'green'}]`

I can run a loop and look at the id and then remove it if it matches but I was looking for a better way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the filter function :

```
things = things.filter(function(val){return val.id!='54'});
```

Comment: filter function underneath actually iterates whole of the array

Comment: @ParvSharma: The point is that you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: The intent is clear, it's standard, in one line, and it's not less efficient that a loop you'd make.

Comment: Thanks casablanca, this looks nice.

Comment: @fancy: This is dystroy's answer, I just added a comment. :)

Comment: @ParvSharma There is no other way to look for the element. Consider a memory space or a garden where there are multiple trees and if I ask you which tree has the biggest fruit then you must iterate and compare right ? :)

Comment: @ShivKumarGanesh - DUDE wht if i keep list of trees sorted by size of the frut they have. this obviously depends upon the the array is maintained is this case.. and the way to not to iterate is exactly what hez asking for.. isnt it?

Comment: @ParvSharma even sorting needs iteration or if you have a sorted array then some extra processing might have gone into it to get so right? Atleast methods like filter solve his/her problem quickly... though it also needs Iteration.

Answer (score 1):

> I can run a loop and look at the id and then remove it if it matches
>   but I was looking for a better way.

You could use the [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

```
things = things.filter(function(item) { return item.id != '54'; });
```

And if you are using jQuery then you are looking for the [`$.grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) method.

Comment: Don't you have your condition inverted? Currently it would keep only 54 instead of removing 54.

Comment: Yeap, had it inverted indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on right track. Go with it. `filter` isnt supported everywhere.

Alternatively, you should create a fallback if `filter` isnt supported.

Code from [msdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
if (!Array.prototype.filter) {
Array.prototype.filter = function (fun /*, thisp */) {
    "use strict";

    if (this === null)
        throw new TypeError();

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun !== "function")
        throw new TypeError();

    var res = [];
    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (i in t) {
            var val = t[i]; // in case fun mutates this
            if (fun.call(thisp, val, i, t))
                res.push(val);
        }
    }

    return res;
    };
 }

things = things.filter(function(val){return val.id!='54'});
```